# Creating a stacked RectangleChart

Tags: plotting

I would like to make a "Stacked" `BarChart` where the bars have variable widths, like a `RectangleChart`. However, `RectangleChart` does not accept `ChartLayout -> "Stacked"`.

Is there a way to do this, or does anyone have a workaround?

For example, here is a `RectangleChart` with the bars at different widths:

[image]

Here is a "Stacked" `BarChart` with the bars decomposed into two components:

[image]

I would like to make a stacked `RectangleChart` with variable-width bars that can be decomposed into components.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, `RectangleChart` does accept `ChartLayout -> "Stacked"`. Consider for example

```
data = Table[{i^2, RandomReal[]}, {i, 5}, {j, 5}];

RectangleChart[data, ChartLayout -> "Stacked"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Great, that seems to work! Strange that the docs don't mention it (http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RectangleChart.html says 'Possible settings for ChartLayout include "Grouped" and "Stepped"').

Comment: You gotta be careful with the wording: "include" does not mean "are only the following". Not that I'm saying its a helpful statement, just that the docs don't mention all the options available...almost as bad as "up to 50% off"...

Comment: Yes, it works, but you have to be careful.  `RectangleChart[RandomReal[1, {5, 5, 2}], ChartLayout -> "Stacked"]` is interesting, but it's not obvious to me how useful it is.

Comment: @BrettChampion It might be useful if you need to draw several non-stacked barcharts in the same figure: `data = Table[{RandomReal[{0, 2}], 1}, {3}, {4}]; RectangleChart[data, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", BarOrigin -> Left]`

Comment: @VLC Interesting idea, although the axes are 'wrong' in that case.

Comment: @BrettChampion There is a tweak for everything. `data = Table[{RandomReal[{0, 2}], 1}, {10}, {10}]; RectangleChart[data, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", BarOrigin -> Left, Axes -> None, Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{{0, "0"}, {1, "1"}}, None},{Transpose[{Table[.5 + i, {i, 0, Length[data[[1]]] - 1}], 
      CharacterRange["A", "J"]}], None}}]`. Might be a good way to look at a lot of histograms.